# create a deep copy by using copy constructor in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I'm beginner in C++ and I have a problem with my copy constructor: I need to do a deep copy, because my class has a pointers. I already defined a copy constructor  and also I create an object `N1(2,3)` from my class `Number`. A second object `N2` is intialized by using copy constructor.

But the copy constructor doesn't do a deep copy because, when I change the value of object `N1`, object `N2` also has its values changed. I want to have two separate objects by using copy constructor.

My class Number:

```
   class Number
   {
   private:
    int* a;
    int* b;

    public:
    //default constructor:
    Number() {
        a = new int;
        b = new int;
        *a = 0;
        *b = 0;
    }
    
    //constructor with arguments:
    Number(int val1, int val2) {
        a = new int;
        b = new int;
        *a = val1; 
        *b = val2;
    }
    //copy constructor:
    Number(const Number& other) {
        a = new int;
        b = new int;
       *a = *(other.a)
       *b = *(other.b);
    }

    //getters and setters:
    int getA() {
        return *a;
    }
    int getB() {
        return *b;
    }
    void setA(int val) {
        *a = val;
    }
    void setB(int val) {
        *b = val;
    }

    //method print:
    void print() {
        cout << "value of a: " << *a << " value of b: " << *b << endl;
    }
};
```

My main:

```
int main()
{
    Number N1(2,3), N2;

    N1.print(); //2-3
    N2.print(); //0-0

    N2 = N1;
    
    N1.print(); //2-3
    N2.print(); //2-3

    N1.setA(12);

    N1.print(); //12-3
    N2.print(); //12-3 i want object N2 have 2-3 values not 12-3 like N1
                           //i want to separate N1 from N2 by using copy constructor 
}
```

I'm trying to define this copy constructor but it's not working:

```
       //copy constructor:
    Number(const Number& other) {
        a = new int;
        b = new int;
       *a = *(other.a)
       *b = *(other.b);
    }
```

Comment: `new int(*a = *(other.a))`?? Where did you pick up that syntax from?

Comment: i already test that :                                                 
 Number(const Number& other) {
        a = new int;
        b = new int;                                                                                                    
        *a = *(other.a);                                                                                                  
        *b = *(other.b);
    }  // but also this syntaxe not work

Comment: Also the correct solution would be to not dynamically allocate a single `int` as that makes no sense

Comment: "i need to do a deep copy because my class has a pointers" no. If your class has pointers that should be not pointers then you need to get rid of the pointers. A missing deep-copy is only one of many issues in your code caused by pointless use of pointers. If this is "I want to practice pointers" ok, lesson to learn here: This is not a use case for pointers.

Comment: There is no need to first allocate, then assign. `a = new int(0);`, `a = new int(val1);`,  `a = new int(*other.a);`.

Comment: `N2 = N1;` calls the copy assignment operator, not the copy constructor.

Comment: *this syntax not work* - [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Your code never uses the copy constructor.

Comment: how can i call the copy constructor?

Comment: important that you read this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: You don't call it; it's called behind your back when you initialize a new object as a copy of an original. Try `Number N1(2,3); Number N2(N1); N1.setA(12); N1.print(); N2.print();`

Comment: @molbdnilo thank you i use this syntax Number N1(2,3); Number N2(N1); and it's work 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code, `N2 = N1;`, does not invoke the copy constructor because `N2` has already been constructed. Rather, it calls the assignment operator. As you have not provided a definition for that, the default is to make a shallow copy (i.e. just copy/overwrite the actual pointers, as you observe).

You need to define a deep-copying assignment operator; something like this:

```cpp
    // assignment operator:
    Number& operator=(const Number& other) {
        *a = *(other.a);
        *b = *(other.b);
        return *this;
    }
```

Note, however, that were you to use the `= N1` syntax in your *declaration* of `N2` (as below), then that *would* call the copy constructor:

```cpp
    Number N2 = N1; // This calls the copy constructor
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're seeing is lack of Complete Rule of 0/3/5.

And the fact that you are not invoking your copy constructor. You are invoking the assignment operator, which has been provided for you, and is shallow.

The line `Number N1(2,3), N2;` has declared `N2` using the default constructor.

The line `N2 = N1;` then shallow *assigns*`N1` because you didn't provide `operator=()`.

If you wanted to invoke the copy constructor, you have to do so at the time of **declaration**. It is a constructor, after all.

Something like `Number N2(N1);`.

In order to complete your code, you still need to write a destructor as well as assignment operator. Then it's time to learn about move semantics.